# C programming socket buffer

Tags: c, sockets, buffer

Re: this client<->server (foodrequest-foodinfo scenario)    I am trying to send receive to a successful client-server connection sock_fd. In this loop, I receive the first information back but the next iteration stops at the keyboard input ie readInFood(). Is there anything wrong with the way I am handling the buffer? or otherwise.

```
RESPONSE_BUFFER = 2200;
INPUT_BUFFER = 100;
int numbytes;
char foodType[INPUT_BUFFER];
char foodResponse[RESPONSE_BUFFER];

do {

    //send a message to server
    if (send(sock_fd, readInFood(foodType), INPUT_BUFFER, 0) == -1)
        perror("send");

    //receive the message
    if ((numbytes = read(sock_fd, foodResponse, RESPONSE_BUFFER)) == -1) {
        perror("receive");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    //end the buffer string
    foodResponse[numbytes] = '\0';

    //print the buffer
    printf("\nThis is the information you require: %s", foodResponse);

} while (foodType[0] != 'q' || foodType[0] != 'Q');
```

Comment: show us the definition of `readInFood()`

Comment: Please indent you code when you post... White space is your friend

Comment: Looks indented to me. +1 for using `perror()`.

Comment: You're sending 100 bytes to the server, even if the user only types 5 or 10 characters. Is the server expecting to get lots of extraneous bytes that it should ignore?

Comment: @Barmar the problem is that the serve is sending a variable amount of data and we are allowing a lot of extra space in the buffer - even though we are terminating with \0 .. does this mean we have to deal with an underrun?

Comment: @Aniket char *readInFood(char foodType[]) {
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("\nEnter the food name to search for or 'q' for quit: ");

    gets(foodType);

    return foodType;
    
}//end readInFood

Comment: Don't put code in comments, edit it into the question.

Comment: also have now tried using memset( foodResponse, '\0', sizeof(foodResponse) ); on both server and client side - still doesn't work

Comment: Just make sure that the server's reading matches the way the client sends. If the client sends blocks of 100 bytes, the server should read that way, and vice versa. But it would be better if you sent just the amount of data you needed, either with a length prefix or a unique delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that your socket is blocking because it expects more information or its not getting anything else. In that case perror() will not fire, but your program will continue to wait for info.